# How to check whether an app is Idle?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a requirement where I need to show a Lock screen , when the app remains idle for certain period of time. In WP7 is there any way to get the Idle time(Any OS APIs). I have gone through MSDN documentation of `PhoneApplicationService.UserIdleDetectionMode` and `PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode` but it is just for enabling and disabling.I need some method by which I can get the Idle time. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there isn't a way of doing that in the current API version.
You could implement a timer in your application and reset it every time there is an user interaction (with your controls) within your application.
The bigger question is how you should handle the OS lock screen? I mean, if your application has an in-app custom lock screen that has kicked in, and then the OS lock screen kicks in, then the user has to unlock 2 screens. Not especially user friendly in that case.